# getting and parsing an XML file in php, then put xml values in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, phpmyadmin

Edit: Solution is that I forgot the query to execute. If you don't execute the query nothing happens ofcourse. Beginners mistakes.

I'm trying to get my XML contents and put them into my database with PHP. I could not fulfill this task with succes so I tried a step back: Just try to insert variable values into my database tables. Also, this failed so I tried to get contents out of the same database but from another table, and that did work. I'm still coping with my problem to fill the columns in the other table, but it is not working.

My code:

```
<!doctype HTML> 

<html>
<head>

<?php  require_once("../includes/constants.php");
       require_once("../includes/connection.php"); 
       $connect = connectDB();   
 ?>

</head>
<body>

<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
$test = "dit is een naam";
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('file.xml', null, true)
         or die("cannot create");

foreach ($nodes->children() as $child)
{
$naam = $child->name;
$desc = $child->description;
$sql = "INSERT INTO feeds (name, description) VALUES('". $naam ."','". $desc ."')";

    print_r($sql);
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

My table (called: feeds):

```
id - INT(ai) 
name - varchar 
url - varchar
description - varchar
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hat this show  print_r($sql); can you show the xml file aslo i see that you did not put url INSERT INTO feeds (name, description) is there in the db a default value for url ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually executing the SQL anywhere.  You need to include

```
mysql_query($sql)
```